# Drawable of Stock loading animation

Tags: android

I want to show a loading animation when open a FrameDialog that implements LoaderCallback.
My only problem is that i couldn't found the drawable. I've searched on @android:drawable/ but with no luck.
I know that could create my animation and use it, but i would like to use the original one in order to preserve the UI.

Somebody knows where can i found it?

Comment: it's not clear of what animation are talking about, exist several versions of loading stock animation on Android, what version are you interested?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just use the [ProgressBar](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ProgressBar.html) view. 
It can be made to show the platform's rotating loader.